# How to write a conditional filter query in SQLAlchemy

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy

I am new to sqlAlchemy.
I want to convert my existing SQL query to sqlAlchemy.

The condition is (If the first name variable is not null show the results with firstName else ignore)

```
...
AND (:FirstName is NULL 
   OR UPPER (employee.firstname) LIKE UPPER ('{firstName}'||'%'))
AND (:LasttName is NULL 
   OR UPPER (employee.firstname) LIKE UPPER ('{lastName}'||'%'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with sqlalchemy functions:

```py
from sqlalchemy import func, or_, and_

db.session.query(
  employee
).filter(
  or_(
    employee.firstname == None,
    employee.firstname.ilike('...')
  )
  # add other filters if needed (and assumed)
)
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: Works when the first name has some value. But in case case when in the request firstname="" 
It returns no Match but ideally what I would like this to do is return all the responses and ignore the firstname filter. I am missing anything here ?

Comment: @codeRider, I'm not sure I understand. null and "" are different values. You can always combine nest various and_ / or_ conditions. Here is some docs https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.or_

Comment: It worked, you were right I just removed None and kept "" in there in the None condition it worked like charm. Thanks a lot

Comment: Happy that it worked!